# Meaning of a block

Tags: hard-drive, memory, storage

From [the Wikipedia definition of block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)):

> In computing (specifically data transmission and data storage), a
>   block, sometimes called a physical record, is a sequence of bytes or
>   bits, usually containing some whole number of records, having a
>   maximum length, a block size.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)) Data thus structured are said to be
>   blocked. The process of putting data into blocks is called blocking,
>   while deblocking is the process of extracting data from blocks.
>
> Blocked data is normally stored in a data buffer and read or written a
>   whole block at a time. Blocking reduces the overhead and speeds up the
>   handling of the data-stream.[2]
>
> For some devices such as magnetic tape and CKD disk devices **blocking
>   reduces the amount of external storage required for the data**.
>
> Blocking is almost universally employed when storing data to 9-track
>   magnetic tape, to rotating media such as floppy disks, hard disks,
>   optical discs and to NAND flash memory.

1. Does block apply to both external storage and main memory, or just
   to the former?
2. Doesn't blocking introduce slack space? How can it reduces the amount of external storage required for the data?

Answer (score 1):

Blocking does introduce slack space but as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_tape_data_storage#Block_layout) states there can be inter-block gap which decreases available space.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.